# Sortable WYSIWYG editor

Tags: tinymce

I have a bunch of wysiwyg editors in a metabox that are sortable. Unfortunately whenever I drag a row around I get this error, and I have no idea what is causing it.

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'destroy'**

This is my sortable code:

```
$( "#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody" ).sortable({
            handle: '.jQuerySortableIcon',
            cursor: 'move',
            placeholder: "topTenSortablePlaceholder",
            start: function() {
                $('textarea').each(function() {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');    
                    $('#'+id).next().remove();
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, id);
                });
                // remove control from our descripiton, and title fields to preserve content
                // tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',true, 'movie_description-1');       
            },
            update: function() {                
                // update the ranking numbers after sorted
                $('.single-movie-row').each(function() {
                    var thisIndex = ($(this).index() + 1);
                    $(this).find('.movie_rank_number').val('# '+thisIndex);

                });
                $(this).parents("#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody").sortable('refresh');  
            }
        });
```

As you can see, on start I am removing control from my textareas (which visually works). The WYSIWYG editors are still below the textareas, after removing control for whatever reason.

If I take out this line: `tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, id);` I no longer get the error, but my wysiwyg editors don't convert back to textareas. I am converting them to textareas to preserve the content within them.

First , what is this error? Is it because its unable to remove the wysiwyg editor when I run mceRemoveControl? Thought I had this working earlier, went with a different method that didn't work out, and have since came back to this route and am now hitting this error.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
It now looks like the reason its throwing the error is because its unable to remove the placeholder. But I don't know why.

It also looks like after I drop my new item into place, all of these styles get added to it throwing everything off:

`width: 1375px; height: 263px; position: absolute; z-index: 1000;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I pointed you to my work in chat, but for any other user, I have solved [repeatable, sortable tinyMCE editors](https://github.com/helgatheviking/WP-Alchemy-Holy-Grail-Theme/) (as best as I could) and have the code available on github.

Specifically, the [JS script](https://github.com/helgatheviking/WP-Alchemy-Holy-Grail-Theme/blob/master/metaboxes/kia-metabox.js) which includes a section on how to disable tinyMCE on the start of a sortable move and re-enable it when sorting it finished.

```
var textareaID;
$('.wpa_loop').sortable({
    handle: 'h3.handle',
    axis: 'y',
    opacity: 0.5,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    start: function(event, ui) { // turn TinyMCE off while sorting (if not, it won't work when resorted)
        textareaID = $(ui.item).find('.customEditor textarea').attr('id');
        try { tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, textareaID); } catch(e){}
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) { // re-initialize TinyMCE when sort is completed
        try { tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, textareaID); } catch(e){}
        $(this).find('.update-warning').show();
    }
});
```

Where `$('.wpa_loop')` is the selector pertinent to my code.

Comment: For those who find the above answer not working, as of tinyMCE 4.x you need to use 'mceRemoveEditor'/'mceAddEditor' commands instead of 'mceRemoveControl'/'mceAddControl'